# List changes when I don't edit it

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

This is a snippet of my code

```
    print (stats)
    print (mstats)
    stats[1] -= round(dam)
    print (mstats)
    print (stats)
```

stats is the list that should be edited but mstats is edited as well.
I don't know why and was wondering how to stop mstats from changing.

This is what the code outputs:

```
['One', 142, 27, 0.025, 12, 2.3, 8, 14, '']
['One', 142, 27, 0.025, 12, 2.3, 8, 14, '']
['One', 133, 27, 0.025, 12, 2.3, 8, 14, '']
['One', 133, 27, 0.025, 12, 2.3, 8, 14, '']
```

The index [1] changes from 142 to 133 in both lists when it should only in one.
Please can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: for further reading: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html
or for a brief summary, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, it is the same list with two different names.

You can check it with

```
print(stats is mstats)
```

This is different from

```
print(stats == mstats)
```

The former shows you, that it's the same object, the latter checks the actual contents, which might be the same by coinsidence.

You probably wrote earlier something like

```
mstats = stats
```

to save you work to fill. This doesn't create a new list, but assigns the same old list a second name. Instead, you have to force to copy the list. For example (there are probably yet more options)

```
mstats = stats[:]
```

or

```
mstats = 1*stats
```

or

```
mstats = list(stats)
```

would do.

Comment: In my opinion, the most readable way to copy a list is this: `mstats = list(stats)`

Comment: Thank you, you were correct.  What does the colon in the first answer mean?  (Please remind me in five minutes to tick your answer, I will probably forget.)

Comment: than yot, I edited it as a possibility

Comment: the colon is a slicing index, like in `mylist[2:5]` - just that you leave out the start and stop, so the defaults are used, which slices the whole list. You can read more in the link in my comment to your question